# Cloud Composer Memory Utilization per Node

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using Cloud Composer on GCP and having trouble diagnosing what's causing a trend I see below.

The first screenshot is of my memory utilization per node in my Kubernetes cluster from the Composer Environments Monitoring tab.

[image: Cloud Composer Utilization per Node]

I'm confused, because when I run `kubectl top nodes` it doesn't look like the nodes are using 20+gb of memory.

[image: kubectl top nodes output]

Can anyone help me understand what the first screenshot is telling me in relation to the `top` output? Things that I've checked so far to help understand what might be causing the slow increase in memory:

- Confirmed remote logs are being written to GCS and not locally
- No tasks are writing files to the local file system, they're using the FUSE mounted buckets for storage.

Thanks for your thoughts

EDIT, showing CPU utilization per node
[image: cpu per node]

Comment: In order to investigate your issue, could you please share the CPU utilization per node as well? Can you also observe if there are an [Worker Pod evictions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/monitoring-dashboard#airflow) ?

Comment: Yes, I will follow up with that. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Updated the post to show CPU utilization per node. There are no worker evictions. I have remote logging turned on, but I'm wondering if the scheduler logs could be filling the workers up?

Comment: I do not see any performance issues with your environment. The command `kubectl top nodes` shows the metrics for capacity in time when you execute it. This article may help clarify the metrics, [link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/193). Did it help you?